# What happens when you say "Amin"?

Tags: allah

I asked something really bad and said "Amin" now i regret mu actions. I want to ask forgiveness. Will the bad happen since i said "Amin"?

Comment: Why are you worry! Don't know what you mean, but if your action wasn't intentional, let the All-mighty forgive you and guide you to the right path.

Comment: It was a mistake. Will the bad happen even if i say sorry?